# Looping through list of stock symbols for daily resampling - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like I am close, but I'm having an issue with reading in the filenames from a list.  Could someone look at the code below and error and help me out?  Looks like I am having trouble using the list to create each filename to open.  This is my first time doing this so I'm a bit stuck on what to do.

```
import pandas as pd

col_names = ['Date','Time','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Split Factor','Earnings','Dividends']

SymbolList = []
read = pd.read_csv('/Users/steve/Documents/MATLAB/all_symbols.csv', header=None, delimiter=',')
SymbolList.append(read)

for x in SymbolList:
    ticker = x
    data = pd.read_csv('/Users/steve/Documents/MATLAB/SNP500 STOCKS 1 MIN DATA/table_' + str(ticker) + '.csv', 
                       header=None, names=col_names, parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
    data['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date_Time.astype(str),format='%Y%m%d %H%M')
    data = data.set_index('Date_Time')
    data_NormalTradingHours = data.between_time('9:30','16:00')
    data_daily = (data_NormalTradingHours.resample('D')
               .agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum'})).dropna()
    data_daily.to_csv('/Users/steve/Documents/MATLAB/SNP500 STOCKS 1 MIN DATA/' + str(ticker) + '_D.csv', sep=',')
```

Here is the error:

FileNotFoundError: File b'/Users/steve/Documents/MATLAB/SNP500 STOCKS 1 MIN DATA/table_           0\n0          a\n1       aaba\n2        aal\n3        aap\n4       aapl\n5       abbv\n6        abc\n7        abi\n8        abk\n9        abs\n10       abt\n11       abx\n12      acas\n13     ack.1\n14       acn\n15       acs\n16     acv.1\n17      adbe\n18      adct\n19       adi\n20       adm\n21       adp\n22    adpt.1\n23       ads\n24      adsk\n25       adt\n26       aee\n27       aep\n28       aes\n29       aet\n...      ...\n998     wm.1\n999       wm\n1000     wmb\n1001     wmt\n1002     wmx\n1003     wor\n1004     wpx\n1005     wrk\n1006     wsh\n1007      wu\n1008     wwy\n1009      wy\n1010     wye\n1011     wyn\n1012    wynn\n1013       x\n1014     xec\n1015     xel\n1016      xl\n1017    xlnx\n1018     xom\n1019    xray\n1020     xrx\n1021     xto\n1022     xyl\n1023     ynr\n1024     yum\n1025     zbh\n1026    zion\n1027     zts\n\n[1028 rows x 1 columns].csv' does not exist

Comment: So `read` should be a `DataFrame` and then you are adding it to `SymbolList`, so symbol list is a list that contains a `DataFrame`. When you then use `str(ticker)` you are literally converting your `DataFrame` into a string. My guess is you want something like `SymbolList = read[0].tolist()`, to actually get the tickers symbols into the list.

Comment: I think that worked!  Thanks for having a look.  If anyone else has other methods, this is a good learning exercise for me :)

Comment: You don't really need `SymbolList` (except if you use it later), you can do directly `for x in read[0]:` it will iterate through the row of the first column of `read`.